# Spark/Spark Streaming in production without HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I have been developing applications using Spark/Spark-Streaming but so far always used HDFS for file storage. However, I have reached a stage where I am exploring if it can be done (in production, running 24/7) without HDFS. I tried sieving though Spark user group but have not found any concrete answer so far. Note that I do use checkpoints and stateful stream processing using **updateStateByKey**.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the streaming(I've been using Kafka), you do not need to use checkpoints etc.

Since spark 1.3 they have implemented a direct approach with so many benefits.

> Simplified Parallelism: No need to create multiple input Kafka streams
>   and union-ing them. With directStream, Spark Streaming will create as
>   many RDD partitions as there is Kafka partitions to consume, which
>   will all read data from Kafka in parallel. So there is one-to-one
>   mapping between Kafka and RDD partitions, which is easier to
>   understand and tune.
>
> Efficiency: Achieving zero-data loss in the first approach required
>   the data to be stored in a Write Ahead Log, which further replicated
>   the data. This is actually inefficient as the data effectively gets
>   replicated twice - once by Kafka, and a second time by the Write Ahead
>   Log. This second approach eliminate the problem as there is no
>   receiver, and hence no need for Write Ahead Logs.
>
> Exactly-once semantics: The first approach uses Kafka’s high level API
>   to store consumed offsets in Zookeeper. This is traditionally the way
>   to consume data from Kafka. While this approach (in combination with
>   write ahead logs) can ensure zero data loss (i.e. at-least once
>   semantics), there is a small chance some records may get consumed
>   twice under some failures. This occurs because of inconsistencies
>   between data reliably received by Spark Streaming and offsets tracked
>   by Zookeeper. Hence, in this second approach, we use simple Kafka API
>   that does not use Zookeeper and offsets tracked only by Spark
>   Streaming within its checkpoints. This eliminates inconsistencies
>   between Spark Streaming and Zookeeper/Kafka, and so each record is
>   received by Spark Streaming effectively exactly once despite failures.

If you are using Kafka, you can found out more here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Approach 2.